# Getting different result when converting keras model into tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow

I'm trying to convert my Keras model into .pb format to be used in TensorFlow (specifically c# to import into Unity at some later stage). I have 4 output layers that return a heatmap. When I use the model in Keras it predicts input images correctly, however, when I convert it into .pb format and predict using TensorFlow, the output is completely different.

Here is my model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import backend as K
import keras
from keras.models import Model
import h5py
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util

model = load_model('my_model.hdf5')
```

Predicting using Keras (for one output layer):

```
def get_layer_output(model, layer_name, data):
    intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                                 outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
    layer_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict([data])

    return layer_output

layer_pos = 'pos_out'

pos_output = get_layer_output(model, layer_pos, input_image)
```

This predicts the input image for some layer in the model and returns a heatmap.

Output prediction (Keras):
[image]

Keras correctly predicted the input which was a 2D depth image.

Here is a summary of my Keras model if that helps:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 300, 300, 1)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 100, 100, 32) 2624        input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 50, 50, 16)   12816       conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 25, 25, 8)    1160        conv2d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTrans (None, 50, 50, 8)    584         conv2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTrans (None, 100, 100, 16) 3216        conv2d_transpose_1[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_3 (Conv2DTrans (None, 300, 300, 32) 41504       conv2d_transpose_2[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pos_out (Conv2D)                (None, 300, 300, 1)  129         conv2d_transpose_3[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
cos_out (Conv2D)                (None, 300, 300, 1)  129         conv2d_transpose_3[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sin_out (Conv2D)                (None, 300, 300, 1)  129         conv2d_transpose_3[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
width_out (Conv2D)              (None, 300, 300, 1)  129         conv2d_transpose_3[0][0]         
==================================================================================================
Total params: 62,420
Trainable params: 62,420
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Now to try with Tensorflow.

Converting my Keras model to .pb:

```
model = load_model('my_model.hdf5')

sess = K.get_session()

output_node_name = "pos_out/BiasAdd" # name of output layer

with sess as sess:
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init_op)
    graph_def = sess.graph.as_graph_def()
    output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
                                                                 sess,
                                                                 graph_def,
                                                                 output_node_name.split(","))
    tf.train.write_graph(output_graph_def,
                         logdir="filepath",
                         name="my_model.pb",
                         as_text=False)
```

The output layers of my model were found via:

```
print('inputs: ', [input.op.name for input in model.inputs])
print('outputs: ', [output.op.name for output in model.outputs])
```

The outputs available are (pos_out/BiasAdd was chosen):

> inputs:  ['input_1']
>
> outputs:  ['pos_out/BiasAdd', 'cos_out/BiasAdd', 'sin_out/BiasAdd', 'width_out/BiasAdd']

The .pb file was then loaded as follows:

```
def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
    # Load the protobuf file from the disk and parse it to retrieve the 
    # unserialized graph_def
    with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    # Then, we import the graph_def into a new Graph and returns it 
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")
    return graph

# Load graph
graph = load_graph("path_to_file/my_model.pb")
```

Input and output was selected from the possible operations:

```
for op in graph.get_operations():
    print(op.name)

x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_1:0') # input
y = graph.get_tensor_by_name('pos_out/BiasAdd:0') # output
```

Possible operations

> input_1
>   conv2d_1/kernel
>   conv2d_1/kernel/read
>   conv2d_1/bias
>   conv2d_1/bias/read
>   conv2d_1/convolution
>   conv2d_1/BiasAdd
>   conv2d_1/Relu
>   conv2d_2/kernel
>   conv2d_2/kernel/read
>   conv2d_2/bias
>   conv2d_2/bias/read
>   conv2d_2/convolution
>   conv2d_2/BiasAdd
>   conv2d_2/Relu
>   conv2d_3/kernel
>   conv2d_3/kernel/read
>   conv2d_3/bias
>   conv2d_3/bias/read
>   conv2d_3/convolution
>   conv2d_3/BiasAdd
>   conv2d_3/Relu
>   conv2d_transpose_1/kernel
>   conv2d_transpose_1/kernel/read
>   conv2d_transpose_1/bias
>   conv2d_transpose_1/bias/read
>   conv2d_transpose_1/Shape
>   conv2d_transpose_1/strided_slice/stack
>   conv2d_transpose_1/strided_slice/stack_1
>   conv2d_transpose_1/strided_slice/stack_2
>   conv2d_transpose_1/strided_slice
>   conv2d_transpose_1/strided_slice_1/stack
>   conv2d_transpose_1/strided_slice_1/stack_1
>   conv2d_transpose_1/strided_slice_1/stack_2
>   conv2d_transpose_1/strided_slice_1
>   conv2d_transpose_1/strided_slice_2/stack
>   conv2d_transpose_1/strided_slice_2/stack_1
>   conv2d_transpose_1/strided_slice_2/stack_2
>   conv2d_transpose_1/strided_slice_2
>   conv2d_transpose_1/mul/y
>   conv2d_transpose_1/mul
>   conv2d_transpose_1/mul_1/y
>   conv2d_transpose_1/mul_1
>   conv2d_transpose_1/stack/3
>   conv2d_transpose_1/stack
>   conv2d_transpose_1/conv2d_transpose
>   conv2d_transpose_1/BiasAdd
>   conv2d_transpose_1/Relu
>   conv2d_transpose_2/kernel
>   conv2d_transpose_2/kernel/read
>   conv2d_transpose_2/bias
>   conv2d_transpose_2/bias/read
>   conv2d_transpose_2/Shape
>   conv2d_transpose_2/strided_slice/stack
>   conv2d_transpose_2/strided_slice/stack_1
>   conv2d_transpose_2/strided_slice/stack_2
>   conv2d_transpose_2/strided_slice
>   conv2d_transpose_2/strided_slice_1/stack
>   conv2d_transpose_2/strided_slice_1/stack_1
>   conv2d_transpose_2/strided_slice_1/stack_2
>   conv2d_transpose_2/strided_slice_1
>   conv2d_transpose_2/strided_slice_2/stack
>   conv2d_transpose_2/strided_slice_2/stack_1
>   conv2d_transpose_2/strided_slice_2/stack_2
>   conv2d_transpose_2/strided_slice_2
>   conv2d_transpose_2/mul/y
>   conv2d_transpose_2/mul
>   conv2d_transpose_2/mul_1/y
>   conv2d_transpose_2/mul_1
>   conv2d_transpose_2/stack/3
>   conv2d_transpose_2/stack
>   conv2d_transpose_2/conv2d_transpose
>   conv2d_transpose_2/BiasAdd
>   conv2d_transpose_2/Relu
>   conv2d_transpose_3/kernel
>   conv2d_transpose_3/kernel/read
>   conv2d_transpose_3/bias
>   conv2d_transpose_3/bias/read
>   conv2d_transpose_3/Shape
>   conv2d_transpose_3/strided_slice/stack
>   conv2d_transpose_3/strided_slice/stack_1
>   conv2d_transpose_3/strided_slice/stack_2
>   conv2d_transpose_3/strided_slice
>   conv2d_transpose_3/strided_slice_1/stack
>   conv2d_transpose_3/strided_slice_1/stack_1
>   conv2d_transpose_3/strided_slice_1/stack_2
>   conv2d_transpose_3/strided_slice_1
>   conv2d_transpose_3/strided_slice_2/stack
>   conv2d_transpose_3/strided_slice_2/stack_1
>   conv2d_transpose_3/strided_slice_2/stack_2
>   conv2d_transpose_3/strided_slice_2
>   conv2d_transpose_3/mul/y
>   conv2d_transpose_3/mul
>   conv2d_transpose_3/mul_1/y
>   conv2d_transpose_3/mul_1
>   conv2d_transpose_3/stack/3
>   conv2d_transpose_3/stack
>   conv2d_transpose_3/conv2d_transpose
>   conv2d_transpose_3/BiasAdd
>   conv2d_transpose_3/Relu
>   pos_out/kernel
>   pos_out/kernel/read
>   pos_out/bias
>   pos_out/bias/read
>   pos_out/convolution
>   pos_out/BiasAdd

The tensorflow model was used to predict the same input image:

```
x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_1:0') # input
y = graph.get_tensor_by_name('pos_out/BiasAdd:0') # output

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    # Note: we don't nee to initialize/restore anything
    # There is no Variables in this graph, only hardcoded constants 
    # tf.global_variables_initializer()
    y_out = sess.run(
                    y, 
                    feed_dict={x: [input_image]}
                    )

plt.imshow(y_out[0,:,:,0])
```

The output of the prediction:
[image]

Here is the input image if that helps (2D depth image):
[image]

It is a depth image of a TV remote. As you can see the Keras model highlights the TV remotes region which is correct and the TensorFlow method does not.

I've looked online to no end but have yet to find anything helpful for this problem, could someone point me in the right direction if possible?

Thanks.